# Member 'FormWindowState.Minimized' cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#, windowstate

I am trying to call this method from another class.

```
    public void minimize()
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {             
            var min = new MainWindow();
            min.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }));
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Member 'FormWindowState.Minimized' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; Qualify it with a type name instead

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: The type is`FormWindowState`. You're using `WindowState` which is an instance property.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I did that and now I'm getting this error: cannot implicity convert type System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowsState to System.Window.WindowState. An explicit conversion exists.

Comment: You're mixing WPF and WinForms...

Comment: Since I put FormWindowState, yes I am.

Comment: Hmmmm however your original error message is about the WinForms property. Are you calling that code from inside a `Form`? Use the fully qualified name `System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized`

Answer (score -2):

I figured the error: 
What I was trying to do is to access the state of an undefined window. What needed to be done is to get the current window through the GetWindow() method and then set the WindowState of the current window as minimized. Here the full code

```
var min = new MainWindow();
Window window = Window.GetWindow(min);
Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```